# Is there a way to assign a default Category to a Post when the user creates a new Post?

Tags: hooks, admin, post-editor

So far the best I've been able to figure out is how to assign a category when the Save Draft button is pressed. That is not what users want. They want to a particular Category ticked when they first go to create the Post.

I guess what I'm asking is: Is there a hook which fires -before- the initial draft post is created, but -before- it is displayed in the Admin editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress presents default category as a setting in Settings -> Writing (though this doesn't seem to pre-check the checkbox):

[image: WordPress Writing settings]

[The `new_to_auto-draft` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/old_status_to_new_status/) will allow you to do things to a new post before the page loads, and does pre-check the checkbox (tested):

```php
add_action( 'new_to_auto-draft', static function ( $post ) {
    $default_category_id = 25; // The ID of your default category.
    wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, $default_category_id, 'category' );
} );
```

Comment: Well that was easier than expected. :D Where are these hooks documented? I did a Google search for new_to_auto_draft and got no direct reference in Codex,

Comment: Yeah, `new_to_auto-draft` will not appear in search results because the hook is dynamic, in that it uses two variables: `"{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}"`. Check the link provided for more info.

Comment: OK, then another ignorant question. How does one become conversant in that process? Just searching source code? Or does Wordpress provide any tuts on this?

Comment: I used [Query Monitor](https://querymonitor.com/) to review the actions that ran on the "Add New Post" screen, found the hook, and used the stack trace to find the hook in code to then find the documentation URL.